# Произносится ли буква «в» в глаголе здравствовать, если это не приветствие?

Tags: фонетика, согласные, орфоэпия

Слово здравствуйте (здравствуй) в значении приветствия произносится как [здраствуйт'э], т.е. без звука «в».

Если же я говорю, например, живи и здравствуй, я произношу звук «в» для того, чтобы подчеркнуть, что я употребляю это слово в его исходном значении. Обоснованно ли это с точки зрения русского языка? Как выглядит транскрипция глагола здравствовать?

«Мой здравствующий дядя» для меня почему-то звучит странно без звука «в».

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ни в приветствии, ни за его пределами "В" не произносится, иное было бы отступлением от орфоэпических норм.

http://slovarina.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0176.htm

Произнесение "В" возможно только при подчеркнуто внятном, посложном произношении - при слабом слуховом контакте, например.

Вот в "Здравия желаю" - произносится, никуда не деться.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Транскрипцию видел на [викисловаре](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5).

Comment: Это не надежный источник, впрочем, я снял этот вопрос, обнаружив у Аванесова без всяких помет.